# Python - pilha - - balanceamento

Tags: python, stack

Não estou conseguindo encontrar o erro nesse codigo:
Uma sequencia de parenteses "(" ")", colchetes "[" "]" e chaves "{" "}" 
é dita balanceada se cada simbolo "aberto" é "fechado" 
em um momento apropriado

Por exemplo
'([])' é uma sequencia balanceada
'([)]' não é balanceada
'([]' não é balanceada
')' não é balanceada
'' é balanceada
 * Se vier alguma letra/numero (ou qualquer outra coisa que nao seja (){}[]<> a funcao deve ignorar em vez de dar erro.
o meu código:

```
def balanceada(string):
    pilha = []
    for i in string:
        if i != '(' or i != '[' or i != '{' or i != '<' or i != ')' or i != ']' or i != '}' or i != '>':
            pass
        else:
            if i == '(' or i == '[' or i == '{' or i == "<":
                pilha.append(i)
            else:
                topo = pilha[-1]
                if (i == ")" and topo == "(") or (i == "]" and topo == "[") or (i == "}" and topo == "{") or (i == ">" and topo == "<"):
                    pilha.pop()
                else:
                    return False
    if len(pilha) == 0:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

quando rodo o teste:
self.assertEqual(balanceada('([}[])'),False)
AssertionError: True != False

Answer (score 0):

Você tem um problema no primeiro "if" já - "se i for diferente de "(" *OU* diferente de "[" ..." - ra, I não pode ser IGUAL a "(" E "[" ao mesmo tempo - portanto a condição sempre vai ser verdadeira  - e você cai no caso em que não faz nada (pass).

O correto seria pergunta "se i for diferente de ... E diferente de ... então..."  - com `and` em vez de `or`.

No entanto não é a melhor forma - já que o operador `in` em Python pode verificar se uma substring é parte de outra em uma única comparação, é possível escrever, para esse primeiro "if" apenas:

```
if i not in "()[]{}<>": 
    pass
```

Uma outra dica é não usar "else: " e colocar outro "if" dentro - em Python existe a palavra chave `elif` que já faz uma segunda comparação caso o primeiro `if`seja falso, e evita justamente a escadinha que o seu código vai virando.

Acertando essas comparações, a sua lógica parece estar ok - deve funcionar.